# filter the fields with category title and the content (php Laravel jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I need to filter the categories with category title and i used this code but it filters the everything with or without the category

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $("#jobTiles *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
 });
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery's filter function requires a return value so it can decide whether to keep the element or not. You can read official jQuery API for this function [here](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

To resolve the issue, you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#jobTiles *").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
      });
    });
});
```

Second thing is, do not use ID identifier for your HTML tags if there are more then one. You should use ID only if that element appears only once on the page. In this case, instead of giving all your categories a `id="jobTiles"` you should give them a class `class="jobTiles"`. After that your code should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $(".jobTiles *").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
      });
    });
});
```